# How to use hyperledger getnative API for example getState and putState

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I came across the getNative API through which one call chaincode from Hyperledger composer. See here: https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/issues/3120

Can someone please tell me exactly how to use getState() and putState()?

Comment: What did you try? And what didn't work? Please post some example code.

Comment: I also would not invest a lot of time with Composer ... you'd be better served using the updated programming model in the latest versions of the SDKs

Answer (score 1):

Composer is built on top of Fabric. So although the fabric has getState() and putState() the composer generated API does not have same API call. Use the GET to call the Assets or Transactions. Also, read about Historian API. That might help you out. Late move away from composer as its deprecated.